# Connecting flight between Lufthansa and Copa Airlines in Panama with separate tickets

Tags: connecting-flights, lufthansa, panama, pty

I booked  tickets from Cairo to the Port of Spain with a layover in Panama, with one itinerary with two separate tickets Lufthansa and Copa Airlines.

Now I am wondering if I need to collect my luggage in Panama and re-check it in again in Copa Airlines or not? At the airport counter in Cairo (Lufthansa) are they able to print my boarding pass for my 2nd flight or not?

Comment: If it's one itinerary then you most likely don't need to recheck the luggage. But they will tell you when you first check in, and ask if not!

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "two separate tickets"?

Comment: The itinerary has two ticket reference number not only one for the both airlines Lufthansa and Copa Airlines

Comment: If the flights are on different bookings/tickets, you will most likely need to go through passport control, reclaim your bags, and check-in before the check-in deadline. Also note that if you are late for any reason, you would be considered a no-show by the second airline, and you would need to rebook and pay for a new ticket.

Comment: @WaelAhmed: Are the numbers that are different _short_ (5-6 characters) combinations of both letters and digits, or longer strings of just digits? In the former case they are _booking references_ rather than ticket numbers -- a single ticket sometimes have to have different booking references if it includes flights on airlines with different backends.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are able to clarify otherwise, "with one itinerary with two separate tickets Lufthansa and Copa Airlines" would tell me that ***you booked these two legs of your trip separately.***

(eg. you went online and purchased your Lufthansa ticket and then your Copa ticket)

If this is indeed the case, then you will have to:

- Exit the transit area in Panama
- Go through passport control
- Collect your bags
- Head to Copa check in desk
- Print out a new boarding pass
- Recheck your bags with Copa
- Go through security once again to board your outbound flight

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure the answer is: no, you needn't, and yes, they are.

But I think you should ask the personnel when checking in for your first flight.

Comment: Do you have any reference for this?

Comment: @Daniil I flew this route with specified combination of airlines, so my personal experience should suffice. More specifically, it was Copa - Condor - LH.

Comment: So you exist the immigration and do re-check in your luggage also getting the boarding pass in Panama? How many hours You need to do this ? And do you need visa for this ?

Comment: No, we did not need to enter Panama at all, as I have indicated. We stayed airside and did not claim luggage, which was checked to final destination.

Comment: This would apply if both flights were on the same booking, which does not seem to be the case for the OP.

Comment: Unfortunately "two tickets on the same itinerary" is not clear, I'm still assuming they are on the same booking.